# link rel="preload" with PHP and Apache

Tags: php, html, apache

As it's described [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/preload), it might be a good idea to preload scripts and css to make a webpage load faster.

My webpage is based on PHP, so I did:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="preload" href="/styles.css" as="style" />
    <link rel="preload" href="/script.js" as="script" />
<?php
   flush();  // Please, output the code above!
   sleep(2); // Simulate some processing
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>Test
<script src="/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Whats happens is that the webserver holds back the content till the WHOLE script is processed, meaning that the html-code is sent only after waiting 2 seconds, which makes the preload-statements useless.

I tried to add `flush();` before the sleep-statement, but with no effect.

Any idea how to use preload with PHP-generated pages? I'M using PHP 7.x and Apache 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood the idea of "preload"

Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content

When a web page is generated with PHP, you will not see any content until the whole page is generated.

If you force the buffers to be written to the "OUTPUT" using flush() you may want to read the manual first.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Anyway the best place to use "preload" is with resources needed in another page, possibly loading on the current.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I slightly changed the code to make the usecase more clear: With preload, while doing the processing the browser should be able to use this time and load script.js and style.css.

Comment: But it seems I can't send the first part of the html-code with flush(); without turning of gzipping the transfer for example which might be worse than not preloading.

Comment: Yeah, you kinda answered the question by yourself. You have to generate the whole page before sending it to the client (in this case browser)